# Cannot get rsync exclude option to exclude dir

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, rsync

Having an issues with rsync. I'm using rsync as a glorified cp command. I have in a script the following code.

> `rsync -aL --exclude /path/to/exclude/ --exclude='.*' /source/ /destination`

I can get the rsync to exclude any hidden files. Hence the `'.*'`  I cannot get the exclude dir to exclude. I've tried using an `'='` sign, surrounding the dir with double quotes, with single quotes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For clarity, I've tried


`--exclude=/path/to/exclude/`


`--exclude /path/to/exclude/`


`--exclude '/path/to/exclude/'`


`--exclude "/path/to/exclude/"`


`--exclude="/path/to/exclude/"`


`--exclude='/path/to/exclude/'`

Comment: Try `--exclude '/path/to/exclude'` without the trailing /, rsync has some behaviour with it in some case. Otherwize, you can also try `--exclude '/path/to/exclude/*'`

Comment: Thanks Aif, I've already tried without the trailing /. I forgot to add it to my list. Its strange, I gotta be missing something.

Comment: I think this is because the exclude is a relative path, and doing `/path/to/exclude` does NOT actually consider the `/` as the root of the filesystem., this could explain why @Erik's post works.

Comment: @Aif: Yep. If the exclude pattern contains / or ** it's matched against the whole path, otherwise it's matched against the filename

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
mkdir -p test/a/b/c/d/e
mkdir -p test/dest
rsync -nvraL test/a test/dest --exclude=a/b/c/d
```

This works. As `test/a` is the base directory synced from, the exclude pattern is specified by starting with `a/`

Show us the real paths/excludes if this doesn't help.

Running rsync with -vn will list dirs/files - the pattern is matched against the format that rsync prints.

Comment: Thank you Erik for you response. You were on the money. Its strange that the exclude option does not take absolute paths.

Comment: @James P. rsync filters aren't really intuitive... But well, they work, you just have to read "FILTER RULES" in the manpage a lot of times :)

Answer (score 19):

Actually, neither [Erik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343754) nor [Antoni's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277109) answer is fully accurate.

Erik is halfway right in saying that

> As test/a is the base directory synced from, the exclude pattern is specified by starting with a/

It is true that the exclude pattern's **root** is `test/a` (i.e. the pattern `/some/path` binds to `test/a/some/path`), but that's not the whole story.

From the man page:

> if the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular spot in the hierarchy of files, otherwise it is matched against the end of the pathname.  This is similar to a leading ^ in regular expressions.  Thus "/foo" would match a file named "foo" at either  the
> "root of the transfer" (for a global rule) or in the merge-file's directory (for a per-directory rule).

We can ignore the `per-directory` bit as it doesn't apply to us here.

Therefore, `rsync -nvraL test/a test/dest --exclude=a/b/c/d` will most definitely exclude `test/a/b/c/d` (and children), but it'll also exclude `test/a/other/place/a/b/c/d`.

`rsync -nvraL test/a test/dest --exclude=/b/c/d`, on the other hand, will exclude **only** `test/a/b/c/d` (and children) (`test/a` being the point to which `/` is anchored).

This is why you still need the anchoring inital slash if you want to exclude **that specific path** from being backed up. This might seem like a minor detail, and it will be so the more specific your exclude pattern becomes (e.g. `Pictures` vs. `home/daniel/Pictures`) but it might just come around to bite you in the butt.

Comment: Critical typo about the ending `/` in source path. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63165865/9382524).

Answer (score 3):

Following Erik's example you want to do this:

```
rsync -nvraL test/a/ test/dest --exclude=/b/c/d
```

Answer (score 2):

Either of these would work:

```
rsync -nvraL test/a test/dest --exclude=/a/b/c/d
rsync -nvraL test/a/ test/dest --exclude=/b/c/d
```

Note the ending `/` in source path makes a critical difference to how `--exclude` should be specified. This assumes we have:

```
mkdir -p test/a/b/c/d/e
mkdir -p test/a/other/place/a/b/c/d
mkdir -p test/dest
```

Original Post has difficulty when exclude path starts with a `/`. [Daniel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18252050/9382524) is correct that this initial `/` in exclude path might be desirable to exclude a specific path, and that this initial `/` should be understood like leading `^` in regular expressions. However, his answer has a critical typo about the ending `/` in source path.

Comment: Do you know what critical difference the trailing slash makes?  Or just that it stops working as intended?

Comment: @mwfearnley I mean, the way to specify `--exclude` would be different, with vs. without the trailing slash in source path, to make it work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify absolute paths you can convert them to relative paths using [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html):

```
--exclude="$(realpath --relative-to=$PWD /home/file)"
```